# How to stop docfx from escaping "\\" to "\" in c# xml comments?

Tags: c#, docfx

I am creating some XML comments which contain LaTeX style matrix notation.
When creating documentation using docfx the \\ character, which normally denotes a new row in the matrix, is converted to a \.

Is there any way to prevent this happening?

```
///<summary>
/// Blah
///</summary>
/// \f[ \left(\begin{matrix} 0 &amp; 1 &amp; 2 \\ 3 &amp; 4 &amp; 5 \end{matrix}\right) \f]
public void Method()
{

}
```

Output:

```
<p>\f[ \left(\begin{matrix} 0 &amp; 1 &amp; 2 \ 3 &amp; 4 &amp; 5 \end{matrix}\right) \f]</p>
```

Comment: Have you considered \\\\?

Comment: Yes, although reluctant. The same doesn't happen when using doxygen to generate documentation. I am currently experimenting with docfx as an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop docfx from processing the contents of XML comments, instruct to skip markup in the metadata section of the docfx.json file:

```
"metadata": [
    {
      <src etc>,
      "shouldSkipMarkup":true
    }
  ]
```